# Where is the origin of a map made by gmapping?

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I construct a 2d map using laser gmapping, how can I be sure where the origin is? For example, before starting gmapping, if I go in gazebo simulation to the desired center in my environment and then start gmapping:

1. Will that be considered as the origin?
2. If yes, then if I go left by 1 meter, does it mean that now I moved x=-1 y=0 z=0?
3. So with my resolution of 0.5, do I need to translate to ROS by saying : x= (-1 * 0.5), y = 0, z=0 ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/306110/where-is-the-origin-of-a-map-made-by-gmapping?/) by [stevemartin](https://answers.ros.org/users/37019/stevemartin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 361 on 2018-10-18

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are talking about the orign as the coordinates `(0;0)` then the origin is set to the position of the robot at the beginning of your simulation (you can verify that by looking at the position of the frame `map` and `odom`).
Also, if you look at the information of `mapmetadata` there is an attribute `origin` that is always on the bottom right corner of the map but it's not a frame, it's just the *origin* (not `(0;0)` but the pose of the first cell of the `occupancygrid`) of the map created accordingly to have your robot centered at the beginning.

With that in mind, to answer your questions :

1. No, when you launch `gmapping` it creates the frame `map`. `gmapping` can locate the robot according to sensors data and `odometry` so the frame is created at the same pose as the frame `odom`. So your `origin` when you launch gmapping is `odom`.
2. You have misunderstood the axis in `ROS`, you can look at the [REP103](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html). The `x` axis is for the movements forward/backwards. So if you move by `1` meter to the left you are at `(0;1;0)` (if you were at `(0;0;0)`).
3. No, the resolution sets the size of the cells of the `occupancygrid`. So if you have a resolution of `0.01` it means your map will be created with cells of side `1cm`. (e.g.  if you have a map of `10` meters by `10` meters with that resolution you would have `10⁶` cells in the map : calculated with the formula  `map_width/resolution * map_length/resolution`). But that doesn't means that all the coordinates are rounded to the resolution, the coordinates depends of the movement of `base_link` accroding to `odom` (thanks to the `tf`) and cells with simply keep a value if there is an obstacle or not (and if it's unknown). So you simply have to tell `ROS` the coordinates you want.

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2018-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevemartin](https://answers.ros.org/users/37019/stevemartin/) on 2018-10-18**:
So for the 1), does it mean that at the start of the gmapping, the coordinate system of map will start at (0;0;0)?

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-10-18**:
Yes but if you move the robot before creating the `map` frame (i.e. launching `gmapping`)  then its first pose according to map won't be `(0;0;0)`.

**Comment by [stevemartin](https://answers.ros.org/users/37019/stevemartin/) on 2018-10-18**:
@Delb, okay thank you for the detailed answer, now I understood. So the origin reads from the odom.